# problems when setting "/etc/profile"

Tags: ubuntu

I want to set jumbo frame automatically on boot in /etc/profile
the code is:

```
ifconfig enp4s0 mtu 9000
```

but get error：

```
SIOCSIFMTU: Operation not permitted
```

how could i solve this problem?

I tried use `source /etc/profile` to update, but it has the same error.
I have to add `sudo` before `source /etc/profile` and it works.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Comment: Here's another solution. After ubuntu 17.10, edit the mtu attribute in the ’/etc/netplan‘ directory

Answer (score 0):

The location you are using to set this is not intended for it. Please tell us which distribution you are using and whether you run in WSL or not.

**Why is `/etc/profile` the wrong location?**

Primarily:

This would be executed every time you open a login shell or source `/etc/profile` and network configuration is not something that should be changed just because a user logs in or reads a file.

Secondly:

This file is sourced by arbitrary users. If it was possible for any user to change the network configuration that would lead to a security problem. It might be fine in your case. It most certainly is not fine to do it in larger environments.

**Workaround (not recommended)**

In your /etc/profile:

- `ifconfig` is considered deprecated, `ip` is in `/sbin/ip` which you might need to specify explicitely

```
sudo /sbin/ip link set dev enp0s25 mtu 9000
```

or with `nmcli` (network manager)

- *this assumes you have network manager*

```
nmcli connection show --active
nmcli connection show enp0s25 | grep 802-3-ethernet.mtu # make sure that line shows up!!
nmcli connection modify enp0s25 802-3-ethernet.mtu 9000
```

Comment: This is not a programming question and is off topic. Do not answer off topic quesstions. [answer]

Comment: Feel free to suggest a move to a more suitable community

Comment: I did under the question

Comment: This is a programming question under ubuntu. Also, I added tag #ubuntu, so I don't see anything wrong with asking this question.

Comment: @jankinwang Hover over the systemd tag and read that popup. It's specifically disallowed here. For that matter, hover over the ubuntu tag also. It's an operating system configuration question, not programming.